# How to clean string columns (with capital letters and accents) in R?

Tags: r, string

I'm working with the following [dataset](http://201.116.60.46/DatosAbiertos/Temperatura_promedio.csv), which contains average temperatures in each of the 32 states of Mexico.

```
library(data.table)

# Read data from website
col.names <- c('ENTIDAD', 'ANYO', 'ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO', 'ABRIL', 'MAYO', 'JUNIO',
           'JULIO', 'AGOSTO', 'SEPTIEMBRE', 'OCTUBRE', 'NOVIEMBRE', 'DICIEMBRE', 'UNIDAD')
temperature <- fread('http://201.116.60.46/DatosAbiertos/Temperatura_promedio.csv',
                 col.names = col.names)
```

The column ENTIDAD has the 32 names of the states. However, all the names appear in capital letters, and there are some weird numbers that replace the letters which are supposed to have accents:

```
unique(temperature$ENTIDAD)
 [1] "AGUASCALIENTES"                  "BAJA CALIFORNIA"                
 [3] "BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR"             "CAMPECHE"                       
 [5] "COAHUILA  DE ZARAGOZA"           "COLIMA"                         
 [7] "CHIAPAS"                         "CHIHUAHUA"                      
 [9] "DISTRITO FEDERAL"                "DURANGO"                        
[11] "GUANAJUATO"                      "GUERRERO"                       
[13] "HIDALGO"                         "JALISCO"                        
[15] "M\311XICO"                       "MICHOAC\301N DE OCAMPO"         
[17] "MORELOS"                         "NAYARIT"                        
[19] "NUEVO LE\323N"                   "OAXACA"                         
[21] "PUEBLA"                          "QUER\311TARO"                   
[23] "QUINTANA ROO"                    "SAN LUIS POTOS\315"             
[25] "SINALOA"                         "SONORA"                         
[27] "TABASCO"                         "TAMAULIPAS"                     
[29] "TLAXCALA"                        "VERACRUZ DE IGNACIO DE LA LLAVE"
[31] "YUCAT\301N"                      "ZACATECAS"
```

Is there a simple way to replace each of these with the following strings?

```
states <- c('Aguascalientes',
'Baja California',
'Baja California Sur',
'Campeche',
'Chiapas',
'Chihuahua',
'Coahuila',
'Colima',
'DF',
'Durango',
'Guanajuato',
'Guerrero',
'Hidalgo',
'Jalisco',
'Michoacan',
'Morelos',
'Mexico',
'Nayarit',
'Nuevo Leon',
'Oaxaca',
'Puebla',
'Queretaro',
'Quintana Roo',
'San Luis Potosi',
'Sinaloa',
'Sonora',
'Tabasco',
'Tamaulipas',
'Tlaxcala',
'Veracruz',
'Yucatan',
'Zacatecas')
```

Comment: looks to me like this is a read in problem based on R's default handling of non ASCII characters, trying adjusting the `encoding =` paramater of fread?

Comment: I tried the different encoding options: "UTF-8" and "Latin-1", but the result is the same.

Comment: When I run`fread(...,encoding = "Latin-1")` I get the names with the original accented vowels intact...

Comment: Oh, really? I'll try to figure out why it is not the same for me. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have the replacement names you want to change the names in `unique(temperature$ENTIDAD)` to.

If you already have the names you wish to change the old names to you can use `mapvalues` from the `plyr` package to change the names:

```
temperatures$ENTIDAD <- mapvalues(temperature$ENTIDAD, from=unique(temperature$ENTIDAD), to=states)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve you problem:

```
temperature <- fread('http://201.116.60.46/DatosAbiertos/Temperatura_promedio.csv',
                 col.names = col.names, encoding = "Latin-1")
```

Comment: I tried this one before, but I get strings like "M<c9>XICO", "QUER<c9>TARO", "YUCAT<c1>N", ... Not sure how to deal with the <c#> part.

Comment: weird, I wonder why our code isn't producing the same outputs

Answer (score 0):

You can set the encoding (probably better via fread), and use tolower for lower case,

```
x <- temperature$ENTIDAD
Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
# might also want to convert to utf8
# x <- iconv(x,  "latin1", "UTF-8")
cbind(x, tolower(x))
```